# Problem with MOSFET making my current dissapear

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, multiplexer, current-source

The current of 150 mA has to go around 18 different circuits, one at a time.

Now I am trying to use 18 LDOs as suggested below. But now the problem is that the current that is supposed to be 150 mA drops to 10 mA. I was able to figure that the problem is the MOSFET. I plugged only 1 MOSFET without load and the current stays at 10 mA and when I don't use any load just the regulator connect to ground the current is what I expect, 150 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW43Vb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What are these circuits? Do they have something like chip-select or on/off signal?

Comment: I think you should start telling us what is at the other side of your multiplexer.

Comment: What is the expected voltage range being measured?  This sets the amount of voltage drop allowed across the mux circuit, and that sets the technologies that will / will not work.

Comment: Also, what is the control coding between the uC and the mux:  5-bit binary / 5-bit BCD / 18-bit / ???  Some other serial structure:  SPI / I2C / ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find a multiplexer with a high current limit then yes, that is possible. Many chips have a 50mA limit, and multiplexers are typically not used for switching current. It would be better to find a high side switch configuration with a logic level input like this (There should also be integrated high side switches if you need compactness with the current level you desire):

[image]
Source: [3.3v high side switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/3-3v-high-side-switch)

Instead of 12V in this circuit, you could use the regulated 150mA current source. You would need one of these circuits for each of your loads (which is an LED?).

Comment: I tried to use this circuit now as you suggested, but the current drops because of it. Would you have an idea why this is happening? With different MOSFETs the current drop is different.

Comment: Make sure you realize that R3 is the load in the diagram above and your load should be in the place of R3

Answer (score 0):

AN 8-channel analogue mux for 150mA would be rare and thus expensive.

I would go for 18 LDO's with an enable input.

You can place the current sense at the input of the LDO's. It would also prevent voltage drop. For calibration you can switch them all off and measure the current which you have to subtract.

---

> The problem for this solution is that I am trying to measure the resistance of the load and the LDO will interfere in the measurement.

I'll be honest: when I wrote this an an answer I was expecting that the current in the ground pin could be more or less ignored. This from the way LDO regulators work in general.  I did not check this. (Had no time at the moment).

I now have found a datasheet from a manufacturer for a device and the ground pin current is indeed very low: It varies 10uA between null an full load:
[image]
(Beware that not all manufacturers have this information).

I don't know how accurate you need to measure but this error is 0.003%. You could try to calibrate it out. (Or assume it is linear and subtract 1uA for every 30mA output current).

Comment: The problem for this solution is that I am trying to measure the resistance of the load and the LDO will interfere in the measurement.

Comment: What about the resistance of the LDO? I think it will interfere too, because I will be measuring the resistance of the cable + the LDO, and each LDO may have a different resistance and this value may be significant for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use three inverting one-of-eight decoders eg. [74HC138](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT138.pdf) to drive 18 3.3V (or less) drive P-channel MOSFET gates. For example, [AO3401](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401.pdf) which have Rds(on) of typically 60m\$\Omega\$ (85 max) with 2.5V drive so they will drop less than 15mV at 150mA.

The three address bits on each decoder go to the three LS bits of your address, and the remaining two bits feed the chip selects to decode one of 24 (of which you will use 18).

No other components are required.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider building a discrete high-side current source.

Instead of multiplexing the output of the current source, you can add 18 parallel PMOS pass elements and multiplex the gate drive signal. In this case the multiplexer can be a *jellybean* component like the [CD4051](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4053b.pdf).